# Inquiring whether there was a response to email

Tags: sentence-construction

My friend sent an email to somewhere and I just want to know if they responded to him. What is the right way to ask it?

Can I ask:

> Did you get email back?

If not, what would be an acceptable way?

Comment: "Did you get an email back?" is fine, along with "Did you get an email back from [receiver's name]?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure of which person exactly he mailed to, you should avoid using *he/she/they* and try using a different construction like in the examples below:

> - Have you received a response (to your e-mail)?
> - Did you get a reply?
> - Did you receive an answer?

If you do know who is supposed to reply to his e-mail, use *he/she/they*. Here are a few examples:

> - Did they reply to your e-mail?
> - Did he give you a response?
> - Did she answer you?
> - Have they answered your e-mail?
> - Has he replied to your e-mail?

Answer (score 2):

Did you get a {reply/response} to your {message/email}?

Did {he/she/they} {respond/reply} to your {message/email}?

Or: Did {he/she/they} *get back to you* [about that]?

Note: Use "they" if

- there were multiple addressees (recipients)
- you do not know the gender of the addressee(s)
- you do not know whether there was one addressee or many